# applying a mask to a blurView in iOS

Tags: ios, imageview, mask, blur

I have an image that I am trying to apply a stack blur to and would like to apply a mask from a .png file I created to see the clear image below. I need image below to be able to be changed out at given times but the blurView with mask to remain static. This is my code I am using but I do not get the masked image in the blur.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageview = [UIImageView new];
    [imageview setFrame:[self.view bounds]];
    [imageview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"]];
    [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [self.view addSubview:imageview];

    [self setBlurView:[AMBlurView new]];
    [[self blurView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, [self.view bounds].size.width, [self.view bounds].size.height)];
    [[self blurView] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

    [self.view addSubview:[self blurView]];

    imageview.image = [self maskImage:imageview.image withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask"]];

}

- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef imgRef = [image CGImage];
    CGImageRef maskRef = [maskImage CGImage];
    CGImageRef actualMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);
    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imgRef, actualMask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this cocoa controls for Blur Image

[COCOA CONTROL](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/scratch-n-see)

**UpDated Answer**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageview = [UIImageView new];
    [imageview setFrame:[self.view bounds]];
    [imageview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"]];
    [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
 imageview.image = [self maskImage:imageview.image withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageview];

    [self setBlurView:[AMBlurView new]];
    [[self blurView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, [self.view bounds].size.width, [self.view bounds].size.height)];
    [[self blurView] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

    [self.view addSubview:[self blurView]];



}

- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef imgRef = [image CGImage];
    CGImageRef maskRef = [maskImage CGImage];
    CGImageRef actualMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);
    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imgRef, actualMask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```

Comment: That's a lot more than I need. I'm still very new to development and looking for more of just the effect of masking the blurView from a .png. I found this project here [https://github.com/NickTitle/iOS7-Trans-Blur] but it involves using a slider to achieve the effect and after a full day, I still haven't been able to tear it down to what I need unfortunately.

Comment: I am trying to create a static filter of a UIImage comprised of a gaussian blur effect and an alpha mask cut out. So that the entire image is blurred except for the masked shape which is supplied in mask.png. If you look here: [https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur] this is almost exactly what I am trying to do but I want to cut out a mask in the blurred rectangle

Comment: No. Inside the blurred rectangle I want to cut out a shape from my png file, so it is like a window

Comment: Also try this(https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=image+cropper)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to crop the image. The blur is a static view like that from [githum.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur]. All I am trying to do is take that project and use my own .png to create a mask that will cut out a transparent shape from the blurred rectangle.

Comment: right. so can I not create a custom shaped mask inside that view?

Comment: yes, you can. Just add the mask Image before add image as a subview.